# ajax call to local custom JSON file to create Bootstrap 4 cards using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, bootstrap-4

Goal is to have a page with bootstrap 4 cards with an image, title, a bit of text and a read more button. (Essentially a blog page with a list of blog posts).

This has to be done with no server and fully local. Maintenance is not an issue this is a personal site.

---

So my thought process is:

- Have a hand-made JSON file like this: (Stored in `/JSON/bloglist.json/`)

  ```
  {
  articles: [
      {title: "blog article 1", url: "/blog/blog-article-1.html", image: "/images/blog/blog-article-1.png", exerpt: "Lorem Ipsum blabla interesting preview to the site", tags: ["a", "b", "c"]},
      {title: "blog article 2", url: "/blog/blog-article-2.html", image: "/images/blog/blog-article-2.png", exerpt: "Lorem Ipsum blabla interesting preview to the site", tags: ["a", "c"]},
      {title: "blog article 3", url: "/blog/blog-article-3.html", image: "/images/blog/blog-article-3.png", exerpt: "Lorem Ipsum blabla interesting preview to the site", tags: ["a"]},
  ]
  ```

  }
- Then have an ajax call the JSON file
- Then have javascript maybe using Shuffle.JS generate cards that can be filtered, searched and dynamically loaded with a (Load More Posts) button.

---

From the documentation I can figure out how to load more from an API, I can also figure out how to use Shuffle.JS to create a nice grid of images.

What I don't know is:

- How to use Shuffle.JS with Bootstrap 4 Cards
- How to use an Ajax call to call a local JSON file

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
$.getJSON('/JSON/bloglist.json/', function( data ) {
    for(var key in data.articles){
         var out='<div class="card">';
              out+='<div class="card-header">'+data.articles[key].title+'</div>';
              out+='<img class="card-img-top" src="'+data.articles[key].image+'" alt="...">';

               out+='<div class="card-body">';
               out+=data.articles[key].exerpt;
               out+='<div class="cls-for-load"></div>';
               out+='<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).parent().find(\'.cls-for-load\').load( \''+data.articles[key].url+'\');">more...</button>';
               out+='</div>';
               out+=
            out+='</div>';
            $('body').append(out);
    }
});
```